# How to change the title of an icon in Ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework, icons, ionicons

It's just a small issue, but I've looked into other posts but none of the solutions work (at least for me).
I want to change the title that appears on hover. I've tried using `pointer-events: none;`, but it stops the onDelete function

`<ion-icon name="trash-outline" (click)="onDelete(message)" class="del" ></ion-icon>`

Comment: As said below, I just had to use the ```pointer-events:none``` AND change the onClick function to the span (the pointer-events:none disables the icon's click listener (at least thats how I understand it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per the Ionic Forum post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-icon-ignores-title-property/205911) do the following:

```
<span title="whatever" (click)="onDelete(message)" >
  <ion-icon name="trash-outline" class="del"></ion-icon>
</span>
```

and in your css

```
.del {
  pointer-events:none
}
```

[And here is the solution as a stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-iobdes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want any `ion-icon svg title` to show up in my app, so I put this in my index.html  tag:

```
ion-icon {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```